# Can I make Visual Studio or Resharper skip indentation fixing when formating whole document?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, indentation, autoformatting

I'm working on a project where different indentation styles are used. I really like using "format document" option (<kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D</kbd> in Visual Studio), however using it forces change of indentation, which makes our VCS detect a change in every line of a source file.

Ideally I'd like to keep all the benefits of document-wise autoformatting, but skip the indentation step.

I tried to get it done with Resharper (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Enter</kbd>). Resharper has an option to auto-detect indentation, however tooltip on checkbox states that indentation policy will be forced anyway if the formatting applies to the entire document.

Are there any other options to format whole document, but keep original indentation?

Comment: Use editor config